# Bind Database Table data to Visual Studio Chart

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio, charts

We have a local database table called SprintTasks. We want to display this data in a visual studio chart.

Currently, the chart only appears to pull down the first row from the database table.

Is there a way to bind all rows to the chart control? We currently have the code below. Any help appreciated.

```
<asp:Chart ID="burndownChart" runat="server" DataSourceID="getSprintTask" Height="504px" Width="1052px">
<Series>
<asp:Series Name="Series1" XValueMember="sprint_start_date" 
YValueMembers="hours_remaining" XValueType="Date" YValueType="Int32">
</asp:Series>
<asp:Series ChartArea="ChartArea1" Name="Series2" XValueMember="sprint_end_date" YValueMembers="hours_remaining" XValueType="Date" YValueType="Int32">
</asp:Series>
</Series>
<ChartAreas>
<asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1"></asp:ChartArea>
</ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>



<asp:SqlDataSource ID="getSprintTask" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ConnectionStrings:smsConnection %>" ProviderName="<%$ 
ConnectionStrings:smsConnection.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM SprintTask INNER JOIN Sprint ON SprintTask.sprint_id = Sprint.Id WHERE  Sprint.Id = @sid">
<SelectParameters>
<asp:QueryStringParameter Name="sid" QueryStringField="sid" Type="Int32" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Show the code please.

Comment: Added now. Sorry

Comment: That't the mark up, what about how `getSprintTask` is filled?

Comment: @Crowcoder that's it now

Comment: I cannot tell without your data. If you run the same query in SSMS what do  you get?

Comment: It pulls everything as expected, the plots just won't point on the graph. We get one row, twice.